# How to make a spreadsheet that lists products/prices from products of a website?

Tags: excel

Say there is a website that sells kids toys, and I want to write some code that makes an excel sheet that lists all the names, prices, and category of each product. How can I go about doing that?

If this is too much to answer, can you tell me a general term that I could search and do some self learning on?

Thanks

Comment: You may be able to do this with Power Query. Or use VBA. Google "web scraping vba tutorial".

Answer (score 0):

You can use either Apache POI or JS XLS to generate xls.

Apache POI can be used from server side and JS XLS can be used on the client side. You can search with any of these two terms.